# Why the object type is changing uot of 'subscribe'?

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm trying to get Coupon object from the server (REST API + Angular) ,

When im using 'subscribe' - inside the 'subscribe' the object from type 'Coupon',  But outside of the subscribe It's becoming 'undefined'.

What do I have to do to keep his type outside the subscribe in another components?

```
log - 1 :
company-coupons.component.ts:24 **undefined**

log - 2 :
company.service.ts:32 
**Coupon {id: 44, title: "Test", startDate: "2000-01-01", endDate: "2000-02-02", category: 3, …}**


 fetchAllCoupons() {
this.storagService.getCompanyCoupons().subscribe(
  coupons => {
    this.coupons = coupons
    this.coupon = new Coupon(
      coupons[0].amount,
      coupons[0].category,
      coupons[0].endDate,
      coupons[0].id,
      coupons[0].imageURL,
      coupons[0].price,
      coupons[0].startDate,
      coupons[0].title,
    )
    console.log(this.coupon);
  })
```

}

```
getCompanyCoupons(): Observable<Coupon[]> {
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set("token", this.token)
return this.http.get<Coupon[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/company/get_company_coupons', { params })
```

}

```
getCoupons() {
this.fetchAllCoupons()
return this.coupons
```

}

EDIT:
I want to clarify my question. Only out of ths 'subscribe' im getting 'undefined', and i trying ti keep his type outside the subscribe in another components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Firstly we need some informaton about this code. Where did you log coupon object in company-coupons,component?
Secondly, why do you not use conversation in subscribe? For example: ***.subscribe(coupons as Coupon[] => { 
this.coupons = coupons;
this.coupon = coupons[0];
}

Comment: @R.Richards - thank you ,but no. I want to clarify my question.
Only out of ths 'subscribe' im getting 'undefined', and i trying ti keep his type outside the subscribe in another components

Comment: Could you add your `getCompanyCoupons` method to your question?

Comment: @Péter 

1-  ` ngOnInit(): void {
    this.coupons = this.companyService.getCoupons()
    console.log(this.coupons)
    } 
`

2- The list is defined in here: (storage.service.ts)



`getCompanyCoupons(): Observable<Coupon[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set("token", this.token)
    return this.http.get<Coupon[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/company/get_company_coupons', { params })
  }`

Comment: please update your issue with implementation of getCoupons().

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your sample the problem is that getCoupons() function does not wait to fetchAllCoupons()' end.

Illustrated:

1: call getCoupons()

2: call fetchAllCoupons() (in getCoupons())

3: call rest API (in fetchAllCoupons())

4: return this.coupons (in getCoupons());

5: in the future the response come back in fetchAllCoupons()'s method.

Try use Promise to wait fetchAllCoupons()'s end.

```
fetchAllCoupons() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.storagService.getCompanyCoupons().subscribe(
        coupons => {
            this.coupons = coupons
            this.coupon = new Coupon(
                coupons[0].amount,
                coupons[0].category,
                coupons[0].endDate,
                coupons[0].id,
                coupons[0].imageURL,
                coupons[0].price,
                coupons[0].startDate,
                coupons[0].title,
            )
            console.log(this.coupon);
            resolve("some argument");
       },
       (error) => reject())
    });
}

async getCoupons() {
    await this.fetchAllCoupons();
    return this.coupons;
}
```

Comment: The solution was to create a correct synchronization between the actions.
Thanks to you, I was able to figure it out.